# React: how to asynchronously and sequentially remove elements from array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having hard time finding a way to solve quite simple problem in React:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const removeTodoFromDb = (todo) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(['sleep', 'work', 'eat', 'play']);

  const cleanup = async () => {
    console.log('cleanup()');
    if (todos.length) {
      console.log('1', todos.join('|'));
      todos[0] = todos[0] + '*';
      setTodos((t) => todos.slice());
      await removeTodoFromDb(todos.shift());
      setTodos((t) => todos.slice());
      cleanup();
      console.log('2', todos.join('|'));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {todos.map((t, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{t}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => cleanup()}>Clean up</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

StackBlitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aa6wde

I know `todos`, and `setTodos` loose references, but I cannot put `cleanup()` function into the `useEffect` block as it won't be exposed to the DOM.

What is the proper *pattern* for actions like this?

Thanks

Comment: using Interval is another way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove all elements of an array one after another, right?

If so, here's how I would write the `cleanup` function:

```
const cleanup = async () => {
  if (!todos.length) return

  // Use Promise.all to call removeTodoFromDb for ALL todos at the SAME time
  await Promise.all(todos.map(todo => removeTodoFromDb(todo))
  setTodos([])
};
```

Not sure you mean by this:

> I know todos, and setTodos loose references, but I cannot put cleanup() function into the useEffect block as it won't be exposed to the DOM.

Comment: No, that's not it. I want to remove all todos, but one after another, sequentially. And I want React to highlight a todo that is being currently removed. But I also want to understand the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want put cleanup in useEffect just do it.
Activate useEffect when some boolean = true and with help  onClick change it.

Comment: I need to clean up with a button interaction.

Comment: I understand it, I mean you can create [timeToClean, setTimeToClean] = useState(false). And on button change it to true. And create useEffect(() => { if (timeToclean) { cleanup() ...code }}, [timeToClean])